# How to take unique values using xpath php?

Tags: php, xpath

This is my xml. i need to find unique values from the products with there code

```
<products>
    <product>
        <token><code>1</code></token>
        <productName>Product 1</productName>
    </product>
    <product>
        <token><code>2</code></token>
        <productName>Product 2</productName>
    </product>
    <product>
        <token><code>1</code></token>
        <productName>Product 2</productName>
    </product>
    <product>
        <token><code>3</code></token>
        <productName>Product 2</productName>
    </product>
</products>
```

I try like below
i load this in to `$xd_item`

```
foreach ( $xd_item->xpath('/product/token[not(code=preceding-sibling::token/code)]/token') as $n )
{ 
echo $n;
}
```

I need out put like below

```
 product code : 1
    product Name : Product 1

    product code : 2
    product Name : Product 2

    product code : 3
    product Name : Product 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for both following sibling and preceding sibling to be sure that the `<product>` has no duplicate :

```
/products/product[
               not(token/code=preceding-sibling::token/code) 
                    and 
               not(token/code=following-sibling::token/code)
                 ]
```

Then you would be able to loop through `<product>` nodes selected by above XPath, and print any desired part of the product, for example :

```
foreach ($xd_item->xpath(....) as $n)
{ 
    echo $n->token->code;
    echo $n->productName;
}
```